# What will be the proper format for .yarnrc?

Tags: npm, font-awesome, yarnpkg

```
"@fortawesome:registry" "https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
"//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "XXXXXXX-my-token"
```

I am try to configure **.yarnrc** for my project, but I am not sure about the format of the file. I the above format looks fine or I am missing something. Any help will be appreciated.

When I tried to install package using the above format I am getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**For classic yarn (1.x):**

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/13794), it's not possible to use `.yarnrc` for this.  You have to use `.npmrc` instead.

Just [follow the instructions](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) from fontawesome and copy what they tell you to into your `.npmrc` and it should work.

TL;DR:

```
"@fortawesome:registry" "https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
"//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" "XXXXXXX-my-token"
```

**For yarn 2+:**

In `yarnrc.yml`:

```
npmScopes:
  fortawesome:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: "${FONT_AWESOME_AUTH_TOKEN}"
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.fontawesome.com/"
```

Comment: The "above advice" specifically states that it's __not possible__ to use `.yarnrc` with yarn 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `.npmrc`

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=YOUR_TOKEN
```

Comment: FYI, this method is deprecated.  See https://blog.fontawesome.com/locking-the-vault-on-font-awesome-npm-tokens-2/ for details.